# How to replace a line in XML file using ant?

Tags: xml, ant, build.xml

I am having the following xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<power-domains>
                <power-domain name="Security" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="test.module" flag="required" module="com.test.ems">
                            <module-option name="principal" value="admin"/>
                            <module-option name="userName" value="admin"/>
                            <module-option name="password" value=""/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </power-domain>
</power-domains>
```

I would like to replace the following line using ant?

```
<module-option name="userName" value="admin"/>
```

Could you please guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the XSLT task in Ant to modify the document. If you use XSLT 3.0 then it's

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy">
  <xsl:template match="module-option[@name='userName']">
    <replacement goes="here"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```